# Show Selected Category => Product limit in each Page [ 1,2,3,... ] using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

When I click on the next link or any page after page 1, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\RD\view\client\fg-shop.php on line 116
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\RD\view\client\fg-shop.php on line
>   121
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\RD\view\client\fg-shop.php on line
>   135

No products displaying in the page and also the [ 1,2,3,...] link.

```
<?php

  include_once("../../config.php");
  include_once __BASE_PATH."/model/categoryModel.php";
  include_once __BASE_PATH."/model/categoryImageModel.php";

  $catId = $_REQUEST['id'];
  if($fkCategoryP=="")
    $pageresult = $categoryImageModel->categoryImageSelect('status=1 AND fkCategory='.$catId,'sortOrder','ASC','');
  else
    $pageresult = $categoryImageModel-categoryImageSelectParent($fkCategory,'sortOrder','ASC','');
  $total       = mysql_num_rows($pageresult);
  $adjacents   = 3;
  $targetpage  = (isset($_REQUEST['fkCategory']))? "fg-shop.php?fkCategory=".$catId."&" : "fg-shop.php?fkCategoryP=".$fkCategoryP."&";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
  $limit       = 3;   
  $i           = 0;
  $per_page    = 3;
  $pages       = ceil($total/$per_page);
  $total_pages = $total;
  $page        = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)($_GET['page']) : 1 ;
  $start       = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

  if($fkCategoryP=="")
    $result = $categoryImageModel->categoryImageSelect('status=1 AND fkCategory='.$catId,'sortOrder','ASC',''.$start.','.$per_page.'');
  $count = mysql_num_rows($result);          
  if($count!=0)
  {
    $counter = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $id           = $row['id'];
      $catImageName = $row['imageName'];
      $imageTitle   = $row['imageTitle'];
      $price        = $row['price'];

?>
        <div class="cell-4 fx shop-item" data-animate="fadeInUp">
          <div class="item-box">
            <div class="item-img">
              <a href="fg-product-details.php?Id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="../../imgUploads/categoryImage/<?php echo $catId; ?>/original/<?php echo $catImageName; ?>" alt="1" title="<?php echo $imageTitle; ?>"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-details">
              <p style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $imageTitle; ?></p>
              <div class="rights">
                <div class="item-price"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> &nbsp;<?php echo $price; ?></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<?php
    }
  }
?>
<?php include('pagination.php'); ?>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="pager skew-25">
    <ul>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used the pagination for the next page function. When I click the category I need to display the limited product in a each page.

Answer (score 1):

Change 'Id' to 'id' in your code as:

```
<a href="radnus-product-details.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><img src="../../imgUploads/categoryImage/<?php echo $catId; ?>/original/<?php echo $catImageName; ?>" alt="1" title="<?php echo $imageTitle; ?>"/></a>
```

it's your minor mistake. this will helful for you.

Comment: your answer is to view the product details in next page, but i need to display the product. I have 15 product, i made it to display 3 product in each page, 1'st page 3 product and 2nd page 3 product, etc... the problem is in the 1'st page 3 product is displayed, when i clicked 2 page link the product was not displayed, it shows the error. can you help me for this Problem

Answer (score 0):

I don know thats a miss typing or not

```
fkCategory='.$catId,
```

but it should be

```
fkCategory='.$catId.',
```

use this instead of your line

```
$result = $categoryImageModel->categoryImageSelect('status=1 AND  fkCategory='.$catId.','sortOrder','ASC','.$start.','.$per_page.'');
```

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef I tried, it shows extra new error friend :P

Comment: thanks Mohamed-Yousef because of you i found my mistake $catId, but i used in another line $targetpage :)